# Gray scaling the entire view

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a swift based application which shows some events. Each event has time limit after which event expires.

I want to make the event screen grayscale after event expiration for which I have tried things like:

1. Mask view

   ```
           if let maskImage = UIImage(named: "MaskImage"){
           myView.maskView = UIImageView(image: maskImage)
       }
   ```

> above solution not worked from me as my event screen contains colored images as well

2. Recursively fetched all `subviews` and tried to set their `backgroundColor` but not worked
3. Changing `alpha` value of all `subViews` which shows more faded white color

**Query:** My event screen has many colorful images and some colorful labels, how can I make all these in grayscale?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, but what is when you create a View on the Top Layer of your Window, in Grey Color with an alpha of 0.8? Then all UI-Elements under the View should be grayscaled.

Comment: Will the controller objects interactive anymore after doing this? Even in that case the color of images could be seen somehow, but I'll give it a try if user can interact with grayed out views.

Comment: No, UI Interaction is deactivated

Comment: Than it will be of no use, is their any way to redraw all views on top of grayscale view?

Comment: Not really. I guess the easiest way is to change all the colors from any subView, set a opacity of 0.8 and a grey background view at the first level from all your subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've achieved gray scaling effect over entire view something like this:

```
/**
     To convert an image to grayscale

     - parameter image: The UIImage to be converted

     - returns: The UIImage after conversion
     */
    static func convertToGrayScale(_ image: UIImage?) -> UIImage? {
        if image == nil {
            return nil
        }
        let imageRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image!.size.width, height: image!.size.height)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let width = image!.size.width
        let height = image!.size.height

        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        context?.draw(image!.cgImage!, in: imageRect)
        let imageRef = context?.makeImage()
        let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)

        return newImage
    }
```

Here above method will work for all coloured images in presented view and the same can be used for `myView.maskView = UIImageView(image: maskImage)`.

This will grayscale your entire view and while gray scaling only labels and texts I used this:

```
// Convert to grayscale
    func convertToGrayScaleColor() -> UIColor? {
        if self == UIColor.clear {
            return UIColor.clear
        }
        var fRed : CGFloat = 0
        var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
        var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
        var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
            if fRed == 0 && fGreen == 0 && fBlue == 0{
                return  UIColor.gray
            }else{
                let grayScaleColor = (fRed + fGreen + fBlue)/3
                return UIColor(red: grayScaleColor, green: grayScaleColor, blue: grayScaleColor, alpha: fAlpha)
            }
        } else {
            print("Could not extract RGBA components, so rolling back to default UIColor.grayColor()")
            return UIColor.gray
        }
    }
```

Above method is a part `extension UIColor`. Above code is written in Swift 3.0 using xcode 8.1

> Please feel free to drop a comment if concerned or confused about anything in the answer.